# stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, jwt

I have this object with a property with a string in it.

```
class Authentication
{
    public $secretKey = "secret";
}
```

When I use the variable in jwt decode it outputs:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

At no point I made that variable an object.

Here is what I do with the code:

```
$authentication = new Authentication();

$token = array();
$token['id'] = "username_here";

$jwtToken = jwt::encode($token, $authentication->getKey());
echo jwt::decode($jwtToken, $authentication->getKey());
```

Comment: `jwt::decode` you just made an object.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Use print_r to check output of jwt::decode($jwtToken, $authentication->getKey());

Comment: @Efekan Sorry for not saying that. The question was why it outputs that error.

Comment: @JonStirling Cheers mate, didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that I tried to echo the return value which was a object. Originally I thought the problem was the variable.